# If my android phone runs out of charge, is it bad for my mobile?

Tags: samsung

So i have this habit of using my phone till the very end. It isn't like my phone runs out of battery too fast, just that i use it too much. Does this switching off affect my device? Is there any hardware/ software damage sustained?

Samsung J7

Comment: Does the phone has the time to correctly shut down or does it just go off? If it is the latter, then your data may be at risk. Furthermore using a phone until it goes off may also affect the battery in a negative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have personally used the Samsung Galaxy J7 so I can confirm it shuts down properly when it runs out of juice (almost all OEMs including Samsung ensures that the device shuts down properly before the battery 'literally' runs out of power). So no software damage.

Speaking of hardware, using your device between 20%-80% battery percentage would be a good practice. Discharging or charging to the extremes (0% and 100%) affects the battery cycle and can degrade your net battery capacity faster.

Have a look at this - [BU-808: How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries)